# Is it possible to embed a Swing component in a JavaFX application?

Tags: java, swing, components, embed, javafx

I've heard rumors of people creating their own custom libraries for one, but I have yet to find one for myself. I need it because I need to mount another running applet (in a JPanel in Swing) for my application.

Answer (score 3):

No, at least not in an officially supported way.

Comment: Is there any unofficial ways?

Answer (score 2):

There is the SwingView in the [ThingsFX 3rd party library](https://github.com/thingsfx/ThingsFX/tree/master/src/main/java/com/thingsfx/widget/swing) to do this.

I've never tried it, so I can't recommend for or against it.

ThingsFX has a [website](http://thingsfx.com/).

Here is a [screenshot](http://rkennke.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/embedding-swing-components-within-javafx-2-scenes/) of Swing components rendered on a JavaFX Stage using ThingsFX.

[image: thingsfx]